# wxPython not running properly on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, wxpython

I'm new to wxpython, i just installed in on my ubuntu 13.04 by the following command :

```
sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8
```

My system says its installed properly but when I'm trying to run an simple application :

```
import wx
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "My Frame", size=(300, 300))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        panel.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMove)
        wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Pos:", pos=(10, 12))
        self.posCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, "", pos=(40, 10))

    def OnMove(self, event):
        pos = event.GetPosition()
        self.posCtrl.SetValue("%s, %s" % (pos.x, pos.y))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Im getting error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".path./wxTest.py", line 2, in 
    class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Frame'

Please help me with this,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it fixed,

I installed also using pip install which installed some other package name with the wx and i uninstalled wx from pip and then again installed using apt-get install, now its working please use it an help.

Thanks